# Groovy basics - runtime behavior and encapsulation

Tags: java, groovy

I've been reading "Groovy in Action" by Dierk Koenig.
Dierk claims that these are the Groovy tasks that Java cannot perform:

```
- Changing the runtime behavior of objects after they have been created.
```

I thought Java has that as well - dynamic dispatch. Can anyone explain how is it different from Java?

```
- Encapsulating logic in objects in a natural way.
```

How is this different from Java?
Much appreciate your time to respond if you have a clear answer.

Comment: You can create object and then bind new methods to it in runtime. @see Groovy Metaclass

Answer (score 3):

For the first task:

> Changing the runtime behavior of objects after they have been created.

I think you're confusing this Groovy language feature with such concepts as polymorphism in Java. This feature in Groovy allows you, for instance, to [replace a method for an existing object at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444907/is-it-possible-to-replace-groovy-method-for-existing-object), whereas dynamic dispatch is a core feature of the JVM which allows the runtime to dispatch the correct method call based on the actual type of the object.

For the second task:

> Encapsulating logic in objects in a natural way.

I think it's about [closures](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures) which allow you to store references to code blocks or methods that can be re-used. This feature does not exist in Java.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does make sense. I was thinking of polymorphism in Java. Thank you!