# Groovy Meta-Programming

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

In TCL, it is possible to get the code of a method/procedure at runtime, modify it and inject it back.

Is this possible in Groovy? I know it is possible to wrap the original method, but I (unfortunatly) guess that in groovy, the source of the methods is not available at runtime, is it?

example: imagine the following (not quite good) exmaple

```
def someMethod() {
   //some complex code I don't have the source
   println "debug"
   //some more complex code
}
```

If I now would like to change the `println` statement into a `log` statement. I can't replace the whole method because I either don't have the source or don't want to risk that it's different in the next version and thus I would overwrite it with older source.

Thanx to Jayan I am now aware that this might be handled through AST transformations, but it seems to me to be more complicated than it should be.

If I could just get the source through meta-programming and modify it...

OK - I already hear people saying that I need a parser to modify it and that's exactly what the AST gives me - already parsed code. But to be honest, I think a simple regex on the source is often good enough ;-)

Comment: Have you checked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444907/is-it-possible-to-replace-groovy-method-for-existing-object

Comment: Another related resource: http://www.slideshare.net/ilopmar/metaprogramming-with-groovy

Comment: @Jayan Thanx. Those Ressources only show me that the AST is available for meta programming, not the sources. However, if it would be possible to transformiert the AST back to sources, modify it and inject it....

Comment: You can provide completely new implementation for methods.  It appears you want to read "method-source" and then change it by altering AST. That should be possible too;  Please improve your question with better example, some good answer will come soon (from some one else)

Comment: tried to improve my question :-)

Comment: It is now very good question.   :)

Comment: The original question mentions wanting to do this at runtime but some of the subsequent discussion appears to be targeting compile time. Is the question intending to ask how to do this at runtime specifically?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, you are absulute right - when I asked the question, I was with my thoughts more in the TCL world and didn't think about the difference. I guess because I would like to modify foreign code, it has to be runtime since I can't anotate the foreign code, can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all to clarify things:
Runtime Metaprogramming means to have a self modifying program. It changes itself while running. This is usually done by modifying the meta class. Compiletime Metaprogramming means to modify a program before it is running by "extending" the compiler. Usually the later is done with AST transforms.

Groovy gives bytecode to the JVM to execute. There might or might not be a source file available for this, but in general there is no runtime structure, that keeps the source. There is a mapping from the meta class to ASTs, but this basically searches for a fitting source file on the classpath and compiles an AST out of it. If the source is not available to you, this cannot work.

Even if the source would be available, this would not give you the modification feature you look for. A new class needs to be compiled and then something like hotswapping be used to get the class replaced.

Groovy is not an image system like Smalltalk.

Comment: Thanx! I guess this is the answer I was looking for. Didn't think of the difference between runtime and compile time when I asked the question...